# Accessing titles of Biographies in Wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I have downloaded Wikipedia latest dump and parsed it a MySQL Database. Now i have Database table that contains only title and content.My requirement is to extract all biography contents from this table.So i want a dump file that have all biography titles.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a Database table contains only titles and content related to that title. This i got from parsing enwiki-articles-latest.xml. But my requirement is to acquire only contents related to title of category Biography. If i got list of all biographies in  wikipedia i can fetch content from my database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all articles in some category and all its subcategories, you need to use [the `categorylinks` table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCategorylinks_table) and walk it recursively to get articles in the subcategories.

It's not clear from your question what exactly do you want. If you want articles *about* biographies, look at [Category:Biography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aBiography). If you want articles that *are* biographies, look at subcategories of [Category:People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPeople).

Comment: I need articles about people.Can i get all article topics in Wikipedia related to people.Like a mysql dump

Comment: No, you need to walk though the category tree yourself.